# RDP Console Shadow in C#

Tags: c#, console, shadow, rdp

I'm writing an application with **MSTSCLib** to control 4 computers with Windows 7 or Windows 2008 Server.

**This my app:**
[image]

```
public AxMSTSCLib.AxMsRdpClient6 rdp;

rdp.Server = txtServer.Text;
rdp.UserName = txtUserName.Text;

IMsTscNonScriptable secured = (IMsTscNonScriptable)rdp.GetOcx();
secured.ClearTextPassword = txtPassword.Text;

rdp.DesktopHeight = 1024;
rdp.DesktopWidth = 1280;
rdp.Connect();
```

These 4 computers, control 4 power generators.

I need to control from an office computer and keep alive the session, so that anyone can use these computers, physically and remotely. I mean, if I move the mouse remotely, the person who is physically in the computer, see that the mouse moves.

My current situation is that my application connects to the remote machine, but blocks the session to another person. (The session has been blocked, press CTRL + ALT-DEL)

Searching Google, I think what I need is something called "**Remote Session Shadowing**." Is this correct?

How I can do this with **C#**?

I found an [interesting information here](http://rextang.net/blogs/work/archive/2007/07/06/5488.aspx), can be done with MSTSCLib?

Comment: +1 for VNC, but what is the connection with C#? What do you need to automate?

Comment: Just in case ,what are you using for UI (DevExpress ,Telerik ,ComponentOne...) ?

Comment: @Cody: DevComponents DotNetBar :)

Answer (score 3):

I would steer away from RDP, and go with some open source solution such as TightVNC, please look at:

http://www.tightvnc.com/licensing.php

VNC has your desired feature by design.

Comment: RDP can do the job. Please list some arguments why you wouldnt use it. Sounds rather like personal preference.

Comment: Thanks!. I've started my project with VNCSharp, but VNC is very slow. RDP is faster than VNC for this situation :(

Comment: UrbanEsc: I've tried AirVNC, and many VNC apps to Split my Screen into 4 or 6 to control these computers at same time, but VNC uses alot of memory (about 150MB of Ram per computer vs 3~4MB Ram with RDP), VNC is slow and shutdown many times. RDP is awesome fast, lightweight, and stable. Also i need to get the focus of any computer with just a Mouse Over, with RDP i can do this easy. Ahh! VNCSharp crashes when is resized.

Comment: @UrbanEsc: I need to use VNC in my projects because I have to remote controle servers thar record multimedia and RDP messes that up.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunatly it seems like it is no longer possible to "share" a session with RDP, most likely because of license sharing prevention measures.

This means it is no longer possible to log "into a running session" (user already logged in) without logging the other one off.

It was possible in XP, but its gone with 7 (and i'd guess server 2008 too).

You might want to look at Windows Remote Assistance because thats the only option available left which is built into the OS.

Besides VNC you can also check out [TeamViewer](http://www.teamviewer.com/de/index.aspx), which, i have heard, works great. I am not sure if there is an API available though.

Comment: It's possible. Just run from cmd: mstsc -v:servername -console and then Shadow 0. But i want to do this with C#

Comment: I thought so looking at your screenshots. As i said, you need to switch gears, i am afraid, if you want that specific functionality.